# Windows server 2008 r2 - can't create AAC files

Tags: c#, audio, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm looking to transcode audio into AAC. I have the audio as raw PCM and I'm using NAudio to do the transcoding to a file. This is based on the MediaFoundation transform. The code works as expected on my development Windows 10 box.

I'm having trouble getting Windows Server 2008 R2 to work, though. All the resources that I found say that you need to install the Desktop Experience feature, which I have done. It doesn't seem to have enabled it, though. The MSDN article about this feature states that you need to enable everything that the feature brings, but gives no instructions on how to do so for this feature. I've enabled the Windows Audio and Windows Audio Endpoint Builder services, but to no avail.

What else do I need to do to transcode to AAC on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was creating the output file with the .aac extension. Windows Server 2008 R2 only supports creating them with .mp4 extensions. Once I changed everything to call it "mp4" instead of AAC, it worked as expected.